# jQuery onChange not working

Tags: javascript, toggle, onchange

```
function showHide(value) {
    if (value == '2') {
        document.getElementById('toggle').style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('toggle').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

doesn't work, not sure why. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/tJBj4/

Comment: You seem to be rather confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, there were a few errors, here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tJBj4/2/

The errors:

- The toggle's ID was `#toggle` and should be just `toggle`
- The onchange event was pointed to a function toggle, not showHide

Comment: Great, what was it? I can't seem to find the difference.